# Text appearing under NavBar -REACT

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom, renderer

I don't know why when i click on the About icon (or other icons in the menu bar), I get the text under my NavBar instead of having it next to it.

The NavBar.jsx component:

```
import './NavBar.css'
import logo from "../Components/logo";
import { ITEMS } from "../Navigation";
import React from 'react'

export default function NavBar() {
    return (
        <div className="NavBar">
            <img className="logo" /> 
            <span className="textLogo">LOGO</span>
            <div className ="NavbarList">
                {ITEMS.map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                        <li key={i} className="row" id={window.location.pathname === item.href ? "active" : ""} 
                        onClick={() => {window.location.pathname = item.href;}}>                      
                            <div id="icon">{item.icon}</div>
                            <div id="title">{item.title}</div>   
                        </li>
                    );
                    
                })}
             
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

My NavBar.css :

```
.NavBar{
  width: 15rem;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(35,37,79);
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1.25rem

} 

.NavbarList{
padding-top:20px;
  
    }
...
```

And here the picture of what i get (there are other icons above About):
[image]

(I'm not able to put all the css file, because it says "too many codes")

Comment: Check "ITEMS" and make sure all the values have no "About" or "How can you contact us" inside of it.

Comment: I don't think so because when you click on the Dashboard icon for example, the content of each icons appears just under the Navbar... I've added a Page.jsx  and put in on App.jsx but now I still have my NavBar but when you click on an icon, nothing appear. I mean  there still have the navmenu but right to the menubar nothing appears and there is no text under my orange menu bar. Here is the link : https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-leftpad-7xx8rt?file=/Page.jsx

Comment: Have you saved all the code in your codesandbox? A few of the imports are incorrect and some files are empty.

Comment: Yes, I have no errors: here is the link : https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-menu-7xx8rt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Sandbox still has errors and empty files for me. Specifically, imports are incorrect in `Page.js` for `NavBar` and `ITEMS` in `NavBar`, and `Navigation.jsx` is empty. I can fix the imports, but I can't produce the contents of `Navigation.jsx` and can't get further than this.

Comment: I don't understant why they are empty, everything was working fine...But no problem I have managed to fix the issue! Thanks